# big-react-calendar: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'momentLocalizer' of undefined'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, momentjs

I am trying to run the sample code of the [react-big-calendar](https://github.com/intljusticemission/react-big-calendar) component and I am getting this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'momentLocalizer' of undefined`
Here's the code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import BigCalendar from 'react-big-calendar';
import moment from 'moment';

BigCalendar.momentLocalizer(moment); // or globalizeLocalizer

export class Home extends React.Component {    
  render() {
    return (
      <Row>
            <BigCalendar
              events={[]}
              startAccessor='startDate'
              endAccessor='endDate'
              defaultDate={moment().toDate()}
            />
      </Row>
    );
  }
}
```

Any ideas? 
EDIT:The undefined error might be caused by this error I get when I compile the typescript with webpack:

```
==== JS stack trace ==============================================

0: ExitFrame [pc: 00003FDFD9841C1]
Security context: 000002E7B1A0E589 <JSOBject>
1: resolveMappedTypeMembers(aka resolveMappedTypedMembers) [000002DAA69A7881] [C:\Users\simon\Desktop\webapp\node_modules\tpescript\lib\typecript.js:~30820])
2: resolveStructuredTypeMembers*aka resolveStructuredTypeMembers)....

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation fialed -JavaScript heap out of memory
1: node::DecodeWrite
2: node_module_register
3: v8::internal::FatalPRocessOutOfMemory
4: v8::internla::FatalProcessOutOfMemory
5: v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor
6: v8::internal::ScavengeJob::Operator=
7: v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=
8: v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor
9: v8::internal::Factory:::NewFillerObject
10: v8::internal::ParseInfo::GetFlag
11: 00003FDFD9841C1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to run `npm install react-big-calendar --save` before using this in your code.

Comment: Are you sure you can find it among the node modules of you project folder?

Comment: I am not actually running the sample code in the repository. I added the dependency to my project and `yarn install` it. It's not a dependency issue.

Comment: Ok agreed, but it looks like the BigCalendar component itself is not defined. So its eigther not there or is inaccessible.